# method only adding to list if declared inside method

Tags: c#, xml, list

For some strange reason my code throws an object reference error when I attempt to add to the list declared in my class. My _machineName property is visible. The XML exists and has data. I am sure this has something to do with how I instantiated Machines inside the method. Any suggestions? I'm drawing a blank.

```
 public class Machines
{
    public List<string>_machineName { get; set; } //list I would like to add to

    public Machines()
    {}

    public List<Machines> GetMachineList()
    {
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

        List<Machines> _machinesList = new List<Machines>();
        List<string> str = new List<string>(); //List that works
        string zdPath = GetZeroDeploymentPath();

        zdPath = zdPath + @"\ZeroDeploymentService\XML\CatalogFile.xml";



        using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(zdPath))
        {
            xmlReader.MoveToContent();
            while (xmlReader.Read())
            {
                if (xmlReader.IsStartElement())
                {

                    switch (xmlReader.Name.ToLower())
                    {
                        case "machinename":
                            str.Add(xmlReader.ReadString().Trim()); //Works
                            _machineName.Add(xmlReader.ReadString().Trim()); //Fails
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return _machinesList;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you never instantiate the list.  In the constructor of your Machines class you need to add:

```
this._machineName = new List<string();
```

As an aside, a public property should not start with an underscore.

Answer (score 1):

Your property

```
public List<string>_machineName { get; set; }
```

allows you to access _machineName, but you never actually create the List. If you add the following line to your constructor it will instantiate the List then you will be able to Add to it.

```
_machineName = new List<string>;
```

BTW, the name of a public property usually is a capital letter so I would change the name from _machineName to MachineName.

Answer (score 0):

An ObjectReferenceException will be thrown when attempting to act on a reference of your `_machineName` list until it is instantiated, which happens inside of your `GetMachineList()` function.

You will have to move your instantiation of this object either outside of that method and into either a constructor or in the class body, or you will have to call that method before calling `_machineName`

Comment: Where is _machineName instantiated in the method?  I don't see it.

Comment: Actually in the posted code `_machineName` is never instantiated.

Comment: Sorry I misread - `_machineList` is instantiated and `_machineName` never is.